# finding fix points of Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I need to find the fixed points of the following:

dilation on $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$
translation on $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$
inversion on $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$

I'm thinking using Möbius transformations, I know $S(z) = z$ would be a fixed point for a Möbius transformation $S$, and $S(z) = za$ would be a dilation on it, with $z,a \in \mathbb{C}$.

We know $S(z) = z$ gives a fixed point.

Suppose $S(z) = az$ is a dilation with $a \neq 1$, then we can see only $z = 0$ and $z = \infty$ are points mapped to themselves.

Suppose $S(z) = z + a$ is a translation with $a \neq 0$, then we can see only $z = \infty$ is mapped to itself.

Suppose $S(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ is an inversion, then we can see only $z = 1$ is mapped to itself.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Check inversion again. The others look fine to me.

Comment: is this legit though? i feel like i'm cheating

Comment: This is fine. You have correctly summised that $z$ is a fixed point if and only if $S(z)=z$ and have deduced that you can hence solve a quadratic equation (in the extended complex plane) to find the solutions to said quadratic equation.

Comment: what about inversion? i'm not seeing it...also, where'd you get the idea (based on what i've submitted) that I was considering the quadratic equation...

Comment: For inversion we have $z$ is a fixed point iff $S(z)=z$ hence $\frac{1}{z}=z$ which is if and only if $z^2=1$ if and only if $z=1$ or $z=-1$.